# Refreshing Data Connection not Refreshing connected Pivot

Tags: excel, excel-external-data

I have a workbook that connects to several different external sources.

I have code in place that individually refreshes each connection. They all have Enable Background Refresh unchecked.

I have Pivot Tables connected to each of these sources. And while refreshing the connection updates these PT's usually, today I had one Pivot that did not do so.

**Do I need to add code to individually refresh each pivot, too?** I'd like to avoid that if it's uneccesary, because otherwise I'd be refreshing each pivot twice (once when the connection updates, and then again immediately after). Not trying to add extra delays to the already long refresh process.

Thoughts? Thanks!